# Can I extend the Superbar to fit on both my screens

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, superbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Dual Monitor - Taskbar with Start Menu on both Monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/43252/windows-7-dual-monitor-taskbar-with-start-menu-on-both-monitors)

I am using Windows 7 RTM with dual screen setup.

Is is possible to have the superbar on both screens ? That way I can fit in many more shortcuts of programs on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya or you could use display Fusion http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/ They have complete Win7 Support

Comment: Is it possible without using any software, just by customizing the Windows 7 interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like [Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) and Actual Multiple Monitors to extend the taskbar however, I'm not sure that they can replicate the Superbar functionality (like pinning applications).

You could always use the old Quick Launch capability - it hasn't gone away. Or perhaps you can extend the taskbar vertically (drag the top edge of the taskbar up another row or two).

But to be honest, you have an (easily accessible) desktop (or two) that you could fill with shortcuts, a configurable Start Menu list and a searchable All Programs section - do you really need two taskbars full of pinned shortcuts?

Comment: yea i do like my shortcuts on the superbar, my desktop i use for other stuff.. but then that a secret I'm not telling you :p