# How can I duplicate Windows 7 task bar - WITH clock, notification, and start bar on extended desktop?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, start-menu

Windows 8 was a bust, enabled duplicate task bars but no notification area. I've tried UltraMon, and saw some other software but nothing actually duplicates the notification area on an extended desktop.

Anyone seena  solution?

Comment: Also see [Mirroring Windows 7 Taskbar on Multiple Displays](http://superuser.com/questions/217720/mirroring-windows-7-taskbar-on-multiple-displays), [Is there a way to duplicate the taskbar across multiple monitors in windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/22273/is-there-a-way-to-duplicate-the-taskbar-across-multiple-monitors-in-windows-7), [Can I extend the Superbar to fit on both my screens](http://superuser.com/questions/57291), [How do I get the Windows 7 taskbar with the Start Menu to display on dual monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/43252) etc.

Answer (score 6):

[Dual Monitor Taskbar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/) works well if you only use two screens.

Comment: +1 for being free, seems to work well, pretty straightforward

Comment: It looks fine, but it has some bugs. After a while, some of the applications disappeared from the "new" start bar, even if they were open. And a small problem: the windows from the second screen seem to be minimized on the first one.

Answer (score 3):

[DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) will duplicate the entire taskbar - including the start menu, notification area, and clock. You can customize the second taskbar to use larger icons, format the clock differently, etc.

Comment: Can confirm that DisplayFusion is definitely the best app I've seen thus far for dual monitors. Replicates notification bar and everything.

Comment: Yeah, I love it. It's the first program I bought besides Windows.

Comment: Looks like this feature requirs the pro version, though

Comment: Doesn't copy everything, I'm a little disapointed.