# Mirroring Windows 7 Taskbar on Multiple Displays

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Dual Monitor - Taskbar with Start Menu on both Monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/43252/windows-7-dual-monitor-taskbar-with-start-menu-on-both-monitors)

Is there any way to get the taskbar in Windows 7 to show up on multiple displays. It's really annoying to have to go to one monitor to switch between programs running on a second monitor. Same goes for the ALT-TAB helper, it only shows up on the first monitor even though I want to switch between programs on the second monitor.

EDIT: Here's the link to the question without the taskbar portion, obviously not a duplicate:
[Mirroring Windows 7 ALT-TAB and Win+TAB on multiple monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/218095/mirroring-windows-7-alt-tab-and-wintab-on-multiple-monitors)

Comment: How is it exact duplicate if ALT-TAB isn't mentioned in the other question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) has an option to display a taskbar on each screen, but it's pretty pricey.