# Mirroring Windows 7 ALT-TAB and Win+TAB on multiple monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

Is there any way to get the ALT-TAB and Win+TAB application switcher to display on multiple monitors in Windows 7?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### [Actual Window Manager](http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/dual_monitor_taskbar_task_switcher_and_other_multi_monitor_enhancements.shtml)

> The Multi-monitor Task Switcher simultaneously displays the Task Switcher service window on both monitors. This avoids a user having to switch attention from the second monitor when hitting Alt+Tab.

Don't believe there is any hack or utility that can show 3D Flip across all monitors though.

*FYI: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> = Task Switcher. <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> = Flip 3D*

Comment: works in win 8 too. Pretty expensive though if you only use it to duplicate the alt-tab window...

Comment: Here's the link http://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/download/

Comment: Also note that its a 30-day trial or $25 product.

Comment: At that price you might want to consider [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/WindowManagement/) which includes that feature and much more...

Answer (score 7):

There's also [VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher/multiple-monitors.html) (free). It works in Windows 7, despite its name. It replaces the application switcher with it's own, so I guess it depends on if you like that or not. I just installed it and initially it seems good.

> With VistaSwitcher, the choice is always yours. VistaSwitcher shows
>   the task switch dialog on the active monitor – the one you’re working
>   with now. The software uses a smart algorithm to determine which of
>   your monitors is currently active – either by the mouse cursor
>   position, or by the active window caption.

Comment: It's great! And the "Show tasks only from the active monitor" option makes open apps list short! Exclusions make it event shorter. I can add open messengers windows, virtualbox windows and all that not so important stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be a little late, but I also had the same problem and found this application, which is *freeware*, and I think it works great:

**Dual Monitor Taskbar (at sourceforge)**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/

In addition to creating a taskbar on the second monitor, it also shows the app switcher on the second monitor.