# How to make the windows alt-tab task switcher appear on the screen the pointer is at

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, alt-tab, mouse-cursor

I have a Windows 7 setup with two screens.

I often use alt+tab to switch between windows but the app switcher dialog always appears on the main screen, which may be a different screen from the one I’m currently working on.

Is it possible to instead have the app switcher dialog appear on the screen that currently contains my mouse pointer?

Comment: Make it your main screen?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I don’t think it’s possible to have the main screen follow my mouse pointer. That being said: this would be a very welcome feature (especially for the task bar), sort of like the menu button now appears on every screen on OSX.

Answer (score 23):

If you just need to switch to another application that is on the same screen you are currently focused on, then Win+Tab may be a better option, as it displays a switcher on each monitor that consists of the apps currently on that monitor (at least on Windows 10, according to comments this is not true for Windows 7 or 8).

The best method I have found to accomplish this on Windows is through 3rd party software [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/), which has [options](https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/AltTab/) to handle if the Alt+Tab handler appears on the current monitor or on all monitors.

Additionally, [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/218095/mirroring-windows-7-alt-tab-and-wintab-on-multiple-monitors) presents a few alternate solutions, though I cannot say which of those are still maintained.

Comment: Win+Tab in Windows7 shows the Aero Flip 3D view but it's completely different in Windows 8 (which cycles between metro apps) and Windows 10 (show Task view)

Comment: Was sometimes hitting one and then the other didn't know the difference great answer thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a FREE solution I just installed on Windows 10 to allow for the ALT+TAB combo to make the dialog appear on any monitor and a few other cool options.

https://www.ntwind.com/software/alttabter/old-vistaswitcher.html

Comment: This thing worked for me, HERE are my configurations : 
preferences > behavior > 
show vista switcherON : active monitor (by cursor position)
`tick`: enable mouse-over selection on task list
`tick`: show task only from active monitor

Exclude unwanted task which are showing when pressing `ALT + TAB` by *preferences > exclusions* NEW add task.

Hope this will help users who use extended monitors

Comment: The compatibility with Windows 10 isn't great, it is showing all start menu live tiles as options alongside with a lot of junk

Comment: 2023 just updade that it still work on on my last windows. just need to exclude some services ( Very easy mechanism Just point and click )