# How to display ALT+TAB on both monitors?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I added a monitor to my laptop but whenever I do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> on my computer it only shows the running applications on the laptop but not on my extra monitor.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: It should work. Are you running any additional software to help with dual monitors? such as a 2nd taskbar etc?

Comment: Nope, I am not. I have it extended monitor but it only shows it on the laptop (which makes me turn my head everytime :/ )

Comment: If you set your monitor as the primary display, Alt+Tab switcher will be on your monitor. There could be 3rd party software which displays the task switcher on both monitors, the default one is on the primary monitor only.

Comment: @Beto, my Mac also displays `Cmd`+`Tab` switcher only on the primary display. Probably it's configurable on Mac. I have never heard it is configurable in Windows though. Maybe Win10 can do it, at least it can display Taskbar on both monitors.

Comment: You may want to explore options from this question: [Mirroring Windows 7 `Alt`+`Tab` and `Win`+`Tab` on multiple monitors](http://superuser.com/q/218095/80304).

Answer (score 0):

I use window 10.
Go to Setting -> Display -> Multiple displays -> extend these displays and choose Make this my main displays

Answer (score -1):

DisplayFusion has options for this.
It's a great Window Manager to run under Windows.

- Go to settings
- Go to the "Alt+Tab" area of settings
- Use the dropdown at the top to change the value to "Show on All Monitors, Show All Windows".
  (There are some other values to experiment with in this dropdown too, depending on personal preference)

Comment: Explaining HOW to do this in DisplayFusion will make this an answer. Right now it is a marginally informative comment.

Comment: Okay, i added that info

Answer (score -3):

just try Windows Key + P

And just duplicate. If you have it on extend your screen 1 is set to priority.

And maybe your gpu in your laptop can't more then just extend.