# Alt + Tab (Switching windows) for Actual Multiple Monitors. Any suggestions?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, alt-tab

[image: 1]

For some reason, my alt tabbing (switching windows) doesn't work. I know it has something to do with **Actual Multiple Monitors** but I don't know why doesn't it work. It doesn't let me alt+ tab for monitor 2 but works for the windows on monitor 1. The picture doesn't appear for the windows on monitor 1 but appears for monitor 2 as well. Please help. The image attached is what it shows, but on monitor 2 there is Internet Explorer running which isn't shown, but monitor 1 has paint running which is shown.

Comment: Link to product not possible due to [this](http://superuser.com/a/58444/138343). I would suggest you uninstall it and use something else if it's interfering with basic functions like Alt+Tab.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you utilize Dexpot instead. It is a free app that has served my needs for multiple window management for a long time now, and should certainly assist you. While it is a bit daunting, you should find what you are looking for in the Window switching options.

http://dexpot.de/?lang=en

Disclaimer: I do not own any stock in, represent, or help develop Dexpot in any way. I have no vested interest in it and the above link is not a referral link of any sort.